# Converting string to javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my user to input some text in an input field and click a button "Evaluate" on clicking that button I will convert that inputted text into a JavaScript object if I could and will show all of it's members(properties and functions).

For example if user inputs `"document"` or `"window"` I will show all members of `document` and `window` respectively.

Iterating through the members of an object is done, but when user inputs some text in input text field and I get that text than that value is treated as String of course how can I convert that text into an object like `"document"` to `document` and `"window"` to `window` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "eval".  **Edit:** Thanks to the comments of @Victor and @Cerbrus for pointing out that **eval** is unnecessary here.  You can also use `window[input]`.

```
var input = "document";
var obj = eval(input);
for (var prop in obj) console.log(prop + ": " + obj[prop]);
```

If it's a member of another object (ie, a global object), then you can use the bracket-notation:

```
var hello = "world";
var variableName = "hello";
console.log(JSON.stringify(window[variableName]));
```

Comment: +1 but I would recomend using `window[variablename]`, it's safer in the question context

Comment: Note: `window["window"]` or `window["document"]` will also work.

Comment: If you're only looking at global objects then you could use bracket notation for everything and have a special case for window. That way you're not opening yourself up to the odd behaviour possible with eval.

Comment: @Cerbrus incidentally, apparently that's also why `JSON.stringify(window)` throws a "circular reference" error -- it has a reference to itself.

Comment: I was going to write the same as Cerberus but got lost in setting up a little example first. So this is just an extension^^ http://jsfiddle.net/xgApL/

Comment: Oh, interesting. So you'd probably have to code in a exception for a `"window"` input, and just return that object...

Comment: thanx all, it helped a lot, this is the fiddle " http://jsfiddle.net/zkHvL/ " that I have created by this help, plz review and update it if it can be done more nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution won't work for sub-properties (ex. window.document.body). I've written a small jsFiddle that should work for most cases. It certainly lacks real error checks but should be a decent place to start http://jsfiddle.net/a6A4m/1/

```
 var showProperties = function(text) {
        var output = '';
        var object = window;

        // if it isn't the global window object
        if (text !== 'window') {
            var parts = text.split('.');

            // Since we're using pop, we need to reverse it first.
            parts = parts.reverse();

            while (parts.length > 0) {
                object = object[parts.pop()];
            }
        }

        $('#content').html(getOutput(object));
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you getting input value like that

```
var selector = $('input').val();
```

Then the object will be

```
$(selector)
```

Comment: You should mention that you are using jquery.

Comment: There is jquery tag in that post.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is JSON format, or the string is a name of javascript object, here a way I saw jQuery.parseJSON do to convert string to object.

```
var s2o = (new Function("return " +val+";"))();
```

suppose val contains the value from text input.

It's kind like using Function object as 'compiler', so that you get return a javascript object.

If user pass in **document**, it give out `document` object;
if user pass in **{id:1, name:"test"}**, it give out that object.